# Scroll PullToRefreshScrollview automatically in android

Tags: android, scrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have a Listview, FrameLayout inside PullToRefreshScrollview. And I'm loading a fragment into framelayout. Data is loading into listview using lazy adapter. I'm able to see the fragment/framelayout while listview is loading. But Scrollview is automatically scrolling to the postion of listview after data is loaded into listview and framelayout is not visible. How can I scroll the scrollview to top? Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView
    xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ptrScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    ptr:ptrMode="pullUpFromBottom" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.xxxx.yyyy.CustomListView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/app_bg"
            android:focusable="false"  />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>



 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the aproach I took

Lets say you have a reference to the PullToRefreshScrollView like so

```
PullToRefreshScrollView myRefreshScrollView = (PullToRefreshScrollView)findViewById(R.id. ptrScrollView);
```

To get the ACTUAL ScrollView object you need to call getRefreshableView() like so

```
ScrollView myScrollView =  myRefreshScrollView.getRefreshableView();
```

and then scroll this object

```
myScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
```

or

```
myScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 teps to make it works:**

1. you should set `android:smoothScrollbar="true"` in layout xml :

   ```
    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
         android:id="@+id/news_list_listView_main"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="#EEE"
         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
         android:divider="#00000000" 
         android:dividerHeight="5dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"  
         android:paddingLeft="1dp"
         android:paddingRight="1dp"
         android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>
   ```
2. and Then,

   ```
    myRefreshScrollView.getRefreshableView().smoothScrollToPosition(lastScollCount);
   ```